# AWS Change ECS Service task definition (deploy) without using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Slowly moving all of our resources over to be managed by CloudFormation which so far has been relatively painless.

I'm hitting a bit of a wall with deployments of new task definitions (staging environment only) on ECS services. There's parts which I don't think can be managed with CloudFormation because the ECS Service is referencing a parameter.

The current process:

- Push to a `develop` branch on BitBucket
- BitBucket Pipelines then handles (simplified):

  - creating a ECR image with the tag of `latest`
  - creating a new task definition revision via `aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json $TASK_JSON`
  - update the ECS service with the new task definition using `aws ecs update-service --cluster ${ECS_CLUSTER_NAME} --service ${ECS_SERVICE} --task-definition $TASK_DEFINITION`

This all works well!

---

Move the ECS resources management to CloudFormation with something along the lines of

```
Parameters:
  TaskDefinition:
    Type: String
    Description: Task Definition ARN

Resources:
  HTTPService:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    DependsOn: ListenerRule
    Properties:
      Cluster: !Ref ECSCluster
    Role: !Ref ServiceRole
    DesiredCount: 1
    HealthCheckGracePeriodSeconds: 120
    TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition
    LoadBalancers:
      - ContainerName: http
        ContainerPort: 80
        TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup

TargetGroup:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
  Properties:
    VpcId: !Ref VPC
    Port: 80
    Protocol: HTTP
    Matcher:
      HttpCode: 200
    HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 15
    HealthCheckPath: /
    HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
    HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 5
    HealthyThresholdCount: 2

ListenerRule:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
  Properties:
    ListenerArn: !Ref Listener
    Priority: 2
    Conditions:
      - Field: path-pattern
        Values:
          - /blog
    Actions:
      - TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
        Type: forward
```

If I were to run the `aws ecs update-service` command manually now the CloudFormation stack would be out of sync with the ECS service.

Had a look into maybe running a `aws cloudformation update-stack` instead but the IAM permissions for the BitBucket user become quite complex.

Maybe I have gone about setting this all up incorrectly here. Any pointers/suggestions here?